# Using ggplot to graph via one data set but color code via another data set?

Tags: r

I'm new to using R and I'm trying to graph using two different datasets.

I know that I can do this:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = dataset1, mapping = aes(x = ..., y = ...)) + geom_point(data = dataset2, mapping = aes(x = ..., y = ...))
```

But what if I wanted to color code via a discrete variable from dataset2, and I don't want to plot anything using dataset2? So, theoretically...

```
ggplot(data = c(dataset1, dataset2)) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = dataset1var, y = dataset1var, color = dataset2var)
```

So I want to plot points from one data set along the x and y axes, then color code these plotted points using data from another dataset. Both these datasets are in the same library.

Comment: You should combine (perhaps through a join) the two datasets so that the color-coding column is added as column to the first data frame. If they're in separate data frames, ggplot won't have any way of "knowing" which values from the second data frame go with which (x,y) values in the first data frame. If you provide samples of your two data frames, we can provide more specific suggestions.

Comment: It would help to see some example data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fill the `data` field, so you can pass vectors (ie: columns) directly to the parameters. eg:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point( aes( x = dataset1$x,
                     y = dataset1$y,
                     col = dataset2$col ) )
```

Make sure those vectors are all the same length. In other words, both `data.frame` objects should have the same number of rows.

Here's a working example, that doesn't require your own data. This will show you how it works so you can apply it to your own data.

```
set.seed(42)
ggplot() +
    geom_point( aes( x = 1:10,
                     y = 10:1,
                     col = factor(sample(1:10)) )
    )
```

[image]